# ERROR: Playwright does not support webkit on mac10.13

Tags: node.js, macos, ionic-framework, npm, nvm

Here is my code debug log6474

```
Darwin 16.7.0
6475 verbose node v16.15.0
6476 verbose npm  v8.9.0
6477 error code 1
6478 error path /Users/------/onet/node_modules/playwright
6479 error command failed
6480 error command sh -c node install.js
6481 error /Users/-----/onet/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/registry/index.js:605
6481 error     if (!downloadPathTemplate || !executablePath) throw new Error(`ERROR: Playwright does not support ${descriptor.name} on ${_hostPlatform.hostPlatform}`);
6481 error                                                         ^
6481 error
6481 error Error: ERROR: Playwright does not support webkit on mac10.13
6481 error     at Registry._downloadExecutable (/Users/-----/onet/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/registry/index.js:605:57)
6481 error     at Object._install (/Users/----/onet/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/registry/index.js:434:28)
6481 error     at Registry.install (/Users/-----/onet/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/registry/index.js:590:26)
6481 error     at async installBrowsersForNpmInstall (/Users/----/onet/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/registry/index.js:780:3)
6482 verbose exit 1
6483 timing npm Completed in 47084ms
6484 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1651869366404
6485 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1651869403151
6486 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1651869403160
6487 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1651869403161
6488 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install 1651869403338
6489 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/playwright 1651869403400
6490 verbose code 1
```

I am so frustrated can any one help I did following I ionic to do nvm  I have OD Sierra should I upgrade.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question

Answer (score 4):

According to https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/1941 You can still install playwright, but only Firefox and Chrome are supported.

1. run `PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD=true npm i -D playwright` to install playwright without the browser implementations

The installation should succeed

2. run `npx playwright install firefox` to install only the firefox browser. You can also point to an existing installation of Chrome or Firefox instead.

Now you should be able to use playwright successfully on macos 10.13

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after running playwright install from pycharm terminal, and part of the error message was

```
Firefox 108.0.2 (playwright build v1372) downloaded to /Users/iop/Library/Caches/ms-playwright/firefox-1372
Failed to install browsers
Error: ERROR: Playwright does not support webkit on mac10.13
```

I figured the installation failed but the download was successful, so I navigated to the folder and simply copied the app files to the applications folder. Worked for me..